# How to access a variable in a parent from its child in as3

Tags: actionscript-3

I am trying to access the variables `healthState` and `healthInt` which are stored in the document class. I have tried `MovieClip(parent).healthState++;` as you can see but I get the error 1120 Access of undefined property health state. The variable is public. Is there anything else I should do when declaring the variables?

```
private function collisionDetection() {

    for (var i = 0; i < enemies.length; i++) {

        var type = getQualifiedClassName(enemies[i]);
        var hype = myMath.distanceBetween(enemies[i],player);

        if (hype < 10 && enemies[i] is Swirl && enemies[i].parent != null) {

            MovieClip(this).removeChild(enemies[i]);
            MovieClip(parent).healthState++;

            if (healthState <= 8) {

                MovieClip(parent).healthInt--;
                trace(healthInt);
                hearts.gotoAndStop(healthState);
            }

            if (MovieClip(parent).healthInt <= 0) {

                MovieClip(parent).desiredLabel = 'GameOver';
                MovieClip(parent).tweenOut();
                gameOver = true;
                removeChild(enemies);
                squares.splice(0);
                enemies.splice(0);
                parent.removeChild(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot cast to a MovieClip because as the error pointed out, that value does not exist inside the MovieClip class.

Try casting to an object instead:

```
Object(parent).healthState++;
```

This syntax should also work:

```
parent["healthState"]++;
```